# What is the best practice for login in/ sign up android application

Tags: mobile, design, login

I need to know what is the best practice to design login/signup for in android apps for best user interface.

### Case 1

Load screen ask to **log in** or **sign up** after splash is loaded.

[image]

### Case 2

Choose login method directly after splash is loaded .

[image]

### Case 3

All together

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the splash an absolute? I know they look good but serve little purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of my thoughts on login:

- **Only ask the user to login if its absolutely necessary**: With this in mind if the user only needs to be logged in to use 10% of your app make sure they can use the other 90% without being logged in. When your app first launches if the user doesn't need to login to start using it don't ask them to do it or if you do make sure they can skip it.
- **Make it easy for the user to log in**: Enhance the api's and other functionality that phone offers to make the users login process as seamless as possible. Provide the ability to login with Facebook, Twitter, Google etc.
- **If you ask a user to enter their password don't get them to retype it**: Instead have a option for the user to show the password that they have just typed or make the last letter they typed visible for a short period of time. Asking the user to retype their password makes the user do twice the work and more chance they will type it in wrong.

On a side note, I would get rid of that Splash screen. Personally I think Splash Screens are fine on games but in apps they should not be there as they make the app look slow.

If your looking for some inspiration on login screens check out [Pttrns](http://pttrns.com/?scid=17) or [My Dribbble Bucket](https://dribbble.com/ElWexicano/buckets/262146-Login-Screens)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this page](http://www.android-app-patterns.com/category/login-screens), it has a lot of login screens. As you can see there, there are many options, including the options you provided. I wouldn't dare to say there is a best practice, given there are tons of options you could consider. What I would say, though, is to consider these things:

- Is a login/signup *really* neccessary? Is there nothing the user could do without signing up? Is it not possible to store data offline? Sometimes you can't get around it, but people have to create yet another account.
- Keep your design spacious. My fingers are quite thick, and so, like many other people, I don't have small fingers like a 12 year-old. Screens like these can get cluttered really fast, and it's annoying when you can't see what you're pressing.

You can't really go wrong with the designs you provided. :-)